# How to set Shutter as default screenshoter in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, shutter

I'm using standard Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity, how come I cannot set Shutter as default screenshoter anymore? I tried everything I knew, I purged it and reinstalled it completely, set it in Compiz Settings Manager `shutter -f` and `shutter -a` ticked the Gnome Compatibility Plugin, even rebooted the system completely still it doesn't react when I press <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> instead basic screenshoter takes a screenshot. Is there something else has changed with compatibility?

Comment: just a guess : are the settings in the keyboard shortcut panel (from configuration panel) the same than in CCSM ?

Comment: @MrVaykadji emm I'm confused, if you mean in settings/keyboard shortcuts/screenshots it says take a screenshot `print` and take a screenshot of a window `alt+print` the same by default in CCSM `print` and `alt print` I didn't change anything either there or there.

Comment: well, you should, since you want to use shutter when you press `print`.

Comment: @MrVaykadji what exactly do I need to change yet except `shutter -f` and `shutter -a`? because I'm confused... I'm using the same settings as I used in previous distros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to keyboard under system settings, and create a new custom shortcut.

[image]

Once created, click on disabled, and once it changes to new accelerator, just press <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> button, and you're all set.

[image]

Comment: tricky! Thank you @Mitch, it works. I didn't even know about that.

Comment: I think it's worth to mention below the answer that if you bind `shutter -a` command to shortcut you will get active window screenshot (not entire screen).