# Ubuntu Hotkeys change

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, kubuntu

Im using a Kubuntu 14.04 and i have changed a hotkeys for brightness control(fn+f2) etc. but kde is to much HEAVY to daily use. Im install unity by command (install ubuntu-desktop)

when I logout and login into Unity i dont known where change my hotkeys i my laptop fn+f2  is brightness down but if i click this in unity this showes me something about battery etc.

How i can change this? and all of my hotkeys?

Sorry for my bad English and i hope you can help me

Cacus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `System Settings` > `Keyboard` > `Shortcuts` and if you desire change them for your taste or create your own.

How to create your own for example [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473067/how-to-set-shutter-as-default-screenshoter-in-ubuntu-14-04)

You can also manage your brightness opacity using `Compiz Settings Manager` install it:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Open CCSM in `Dash` search just type `compiz` launch it navigate to `Accessibility` > `Opacity.Brightness and Saturation` and apply your key configuration in appropriate fields.

Comment: In this metod i must write a new script and its not compatible, notify not show, bar of % of brightness and when i try attend fn+f2 to hotkey it is showes "Battery" and disappears when i do something   move mouse or click something on keybord

Comment: okay just a sec I re-edit my answer

Comment: I have the problem again... i trying to do this that you say but its not working. i tried xmodmap to map my keybord but i cant chanage nattery button to brightness Down i can do this witch other key i can assign brightness down to otcher key but i can not to this "Battery button" when i do xmodmap and after that i do shortcuts in system keybord its not working